# CMake and FIND_PACKAGE

Tags: c++, cmake

What is the best way to ensure that cmake only finds libraries and headers from a specific root directory.

Assuming that:

- we only want to look into a specific directory (example: /mysdkroot/)
- we want to ignore all the files that aren't on the specific directory (for example /usr/lib or /usr/include should not be used, only /mysdkroot/)
- use find_package() functionality supplied by libraries and not specific finds of files or headers on our cmake
- we don't edit the FindXXX.cmake or xxxConfig.cmake supplied by the libraries makers
- important I don't want to edit every find package/file/lib call specifying the path to search for

I can do half of this using NO_DEFAULT_PATH and specify the find path, but i can't have a full proof solution on this because I always depend on the way FindXXX.cmake or xxxConfig.cmake are implemented. For example if debug/release files have diferent names and for example in my /mysdkroot/ I only have debug files and in the system only release exist then for some libraries it might find the release first and not the debug first and other problems because I can't narrow the search to only that folder.

Comment: did you try setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to your sdk root and disabling all other `find_package` search hints? [cmake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package#search-procedure) provides all arguments for skipping certain locations.

Comment: yes i forgot to mention the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, this is the basic for all this to work, as mentioned by Guillaume this with find_xxx flags we obtain what we want, but this is a lot of work to do to obtain a functionality that should be natively to cmake

Answer (score 3):

`NO_DEFAULT_PATH` is a good start. However, I would enable one way to find package and that would be with the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`:

```
NO_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH
NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
NO_CMAKE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY
NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH
NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY
```

This disable them all except the paths specified in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Then set your prefix path to your sdk:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/mysdkroot")
```

Then, indeed you still depend on how those `findXXX.cmake` and those `XXX-config.cmake` are implemented. Luckily, you can change thier behaviour entirely using command polymorphism:

```
set(current-find-package "")

function(find_package)
    set(current-find-package "${ARGV1}")
    # The leading underscore mean the original command
    _find_package(${ARGV})
endfunction()

# function usually used in findXX.cmake modules
function(find_library)
    if("${current-find-package}" STREQUAL "SomePakage")
        # TODO: remove unwanted paths in ARGV
        _find_library(${ARGV} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    endif()
endfunction()
```

Although this would work, I'd recommend **not abusing** it or **be very careful** using this. You don't want surprising behaviour to be introduced.

---

Your concern is primarily with `XX-config.cmake` and `findXX.cmake` trying to find libraries outside your SDK path.

First, `XX-config.cmake` generally behave correctly. If a `XX-config.cmake` is found, it won't try to find libraries outside the path. It already knows where to find those libraries.

Then, you have `FindXX.cmake` that can behave incorrectly since they are primarily written by hand, in different cmake era.

My suggestion would be to replace module that don't behave like you want. Simply provide your own custom `FindXX.cmake` module that behave correctly. If the one provided by the maintainers don't do what you want, don't use them, simply provide your own.

Comment: this is a solution, and indeed this works, if we override all find_xxx funtions and alter the find behaviour with the flags that you mention then we will have the desired behaviour... but this is too much work to do a thing that should be native to cmake... that's my opinion.
Thanks for the contribution Guillaume.

Comment: @Nuno Reading your question, there's a fundamental problem with what you're asking for: You don't want to rely on broken behavior implemented by these libraries, but you don't want to change thier behavior and rely on them. Choose one.

Comment: i want to relly on them, and i don't want to edit their scripts... that's what i meant to say.
Remember that if you put all the flags that you correctly mention on the find_package(...) function this does not affect the several find_xxx() functions that target library might have on their find scripts, so the only way to correctly handle the problem is what you suggest, overriding find_xxx() functions

Comment: @Nuno why would you like to rely on them if you think they don't do what you want? Also, the problem is really with Find module, not config module.

Comment: yes you are completely right, and i totally agree with your aditional notes, but sometimes this FindXXX scripts are the only thing that you have and it's a pain to implement them... i can give you an example the protobuf and JPEG library was two of the libraries that i can remember that give me problems, because they do not correctly implement the find functionality

Comment: can you explain what do you mean with "really with Find module, not config module"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196533/discussion-between-guillaume-racicot-and-nuno).

Comment: When any `NO_*` option is used in the `find_package()` call, it searches only config file, not a `FindXX.cmake`. This is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html). So the phrase "if you send NO_DEFAULT_PATH, all the default paths are disabled from find_library. " (in the comment) is **wrong**: passing `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` doesn't allow `find_package()` to search `FindXXX.cmake` which usually contains `find_library` calls. And even if `xxxConfig.cmake` contains `find_library` call (inside `find_dependency`), it is not affected by NO_DEFAULT_PATH.

Comment: @Tsyvarev reading the doc I was sure it was doing that. I deleted the comment.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your input, and good point, find_dependency is another problem, because even if i only use xxxConfig.cmake then the find_dependency call will look outside my sdk folder... that is what i do not want :)

Answer (score 1):

> ensure that cmake only finds libraries and headers from a specific root directory.

Dependent how "root directory" is a true "root", you may try to set [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.html) variable to that directory:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/mysdkroot")
```

Accompanied with setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*` variables to ONLY, you may force corresponding `find_*` commands to search only under given directory:

```
# 'find_path' will search only under CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE "ONLY") 
# 'find_library' will search only under CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY "ONLY")
# 'find_package' will search 'XXXConfig.cmake' (not 'FindXXX.cmake'!) only under CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE "ONLY")
```

---

The limitations of this approach is that CMake interprets `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` directories as **filesystem root**, not as *installation prefix*. That is, CMake would assume (on Linux environment) libraries to be located under `/mysdkroot/usr/lib` and headers under `/mysdkroot/usr/include`.

You may combine `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` settings for tell CMake about *installation directory*:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /mysdk)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /root) # Not sure whether setting prefix to `/` would work.
```

has similar effect as

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /mysdk/root)
```

But if CMake won't find some things under given prefix, then it wouldn't search `/usr/include` (with `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE` set to `ONLY`).
Instead, it would try `/mysdk/usr/include`. And if given directory is absent on your system, nothing can be found under it.

---

Note, that one cannot be sure for 100% that none of what CMake finds will be located outside of the specific root directory. You may expect `FindXXX.cmake` to be written in a "normal" manner, which uses `find_*` commands, but nothing prevents these scripts to be written differently.